# Pandas - How to create a column with 3 outputs based on conditions on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame     `df:`

```
def fake_data():
     return{'Name': fake.name(), 
         'Gender': random.choice(sex_list),
         'Address': fake.street_address(), 
         'Nationality': 'Zimbabwean', 
         'Account_Type': random.choice(accounts_list), 
         'Age': random.randint(0, 2), 
         'Education': random.random() > 0.5, 
         'Employment': random.randint(0, 2),
         'Salary': random.randint(0, 2),
         'Employer_Stability': random.random() > 0.5,
         'Consistency': random.random() > 0.5,
         'Balance': random.randint(0, 2),
         'Residential_Status': random.random() > 0.5
      }
```

I want to create a column `Service_Level` that is 0 or 1 or 2 depending on the conditions of the columns;

```
columns = ['Age','Education', 'Employment', 'Salary', 'Employer_Stability', 'Consistency', 'Balance', 'Residential_Status']
```

I have tried creating the `['Service_Level']` = 0 with the following, after reading some answers here;

```
df['Service_Level'] = np.where((df['Age']==0)&(df['Education']==False)&(df['Employment']==0)&(df['Salary']==0)&(df['Employer_Stability']==False)&(df['Consistency']==False)&(df['Balance']==0)&(df['Residential_Status']==False),
                               (df['Age'])|(df['Education'])|(df['Employment'])|(df['Salary'])|(df['Employer_Stability'])|(df['Consistency'])|(df['Balance'])|(df['Residential_Status']), 0)
```

Then this for `['Service_Level']` = 1

```
df['Service_Level'] = np.where((df['Age']==1)&(df['Education']==True)&(df['Employment']==1)&(df['Salary']==1)&(df['Employer_Stability']==False)&(df['Consistency']==True)&(df['Balance']==1)&(df['Residential_Status']==True),
                               (df['Age'])|(df['Education'])|(df['Employment'])|(df['Salary'])|(df['Employer_Stability'])|(df['Consistency'])|(df['Balance'])|(df['Residential_Status']), 1)
```

Then this for `['Service_Level']` = 2

```
df['Service_Level'] = np.where((df['Age']==2)&(df['Education']==True)&(df['Employment']==2)&(df['Salary']==2)&(df['Employer_Stability']==True)&(df['Consistency']==True)&(df['Balance']==2)&(df['Residential_Status']==True),
                               (df['Age'])|(df['Education'])|(df['Employment'])|(df['Salary'])|(df['Employer_Stability'])|(df['Consistency'])|(df['Balance'])|(df['Residential_Status']), 2)
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to join these conditions so that I get either 0 or 1 or 2.

If it works, what happens to the states that do not follow those exact conditions? I would like then to also produce and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to use slicing in conjunction with np.where (which by the way takes three argument, condition, val1(if condion is true), val2)

Your first statement

```
df['Service_Level'] = np.where(condtion_1, 0, 1)
```

This will result in df['Service_Level'] with 0s for the rows that met with the first condition and 1 otherwise.

Now you mask the data to get only the rows where service_level is not 0

```
df[df['Service_Level'] !=0]
```

On this dataframe you can apply the second condition with

```
np.where(condition_2, 1,2)
```

to assign 1 to df['Service_Level'] where the condition is true and assign 2 to rest of the rows.

EDIT:

You can use np.where with second condtion inside the first one like this.

```
df['Service_Level'] = np.where(cond_1, 0, (np.where(cond_2, 1,2)))
```

For better readability, you may want to first save the conditions as cond_1 etc and use them in np.where

Comment: thank you, I have tried it and I understand the first condition and the mask but if I apply the second condition I am now getting ['Service_Level'] as 2 throughout the dataframe.

Comment: Did you check if there is any data matching your condtion 2?

Comment: phew, it finally worked. I had to mess with my features a bit. Thank you